# Understanding Currying in Typescript

Tags: typescript, currying

I found this javascript example of currying:

```
function curry(f) { // curry(f) does the currying transform
  return function(a) {
    return function(b) {
      return f(a, b);
    };
  };
}

// usage
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

let curriedSum = curry(sum);

console.log( curriedSum(1)(2) ); // 3
```

I tried to rewrite it in typescript as follows:

```
function curry(f:any){
    return function(a:number) {
        return function (b:number) {
            return function f(a :number, b: number){};
        };
    };
}

function sum (a: number,b: number){
    return a+b;
}

let curriedSum = curry(sum);

console.log(curriedSum(1)(2));
```

The result was

```
[Function: f]
```

1. What am I doing wrong in this Typescript example?
2. Also what is    the type of 'f'? I have just set it to any.
3. What would also be the    return type of each function here?

Comment: return function f(a :number, b: number){}; try without function here just return f(..)

Comment: You have an extra `function` in front of `f(a :number, b: number)`, so you are defining it instead of calling it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function curry(f:any){
    return function(a:number) {
        return function (b:number) {
            return f(a,b);
        };
    };
}

function sum (a: number,b: number){
    return a+b;
}

let curriedSum = curry(sum);

console.log(curriedSum(1)(2));
```

Thanks for the comments, it worked now :-)